# Data is there in HDFS but not fetch in hive table

Tags: hive, hdfs, parquet, metastore

I have loaded record from hive table through spark program, data loaded successfully into HDFS but records are not fetching in Hive table.

Please find below compressing technique which we are using.

```
  sprark.write
        .option(Parquet.compress,SNAPPY)
        .format(parquet)
        .mode(SaveMode.Append)
        .save(s${tablePath}/${dbName}.${targetTableName})
```

Please get me the solution for this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Please Try This.
df.repartition(1).write.format("parquet").insertInto('DbName.TableName',overwrite=True)

Comment: I cannot perform Insertinto to my persist, its throwing error like insertInto is not a member, please suggest what library I need to add.

Comment: I created External hive table. Created a Spark Dataframe and then used the above script.